# Why am I getting NoSuchElementException for this code? Java method for giving users a second chance for correct input

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I'm writing a program and have been having some trouble with my code. I invoke a method called `secondChance()` which gives users a second opportunity to enter a valid input. The method is defined as follows:

```java
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    String val;

 try {
      System.out.println("Please enter file name you would like to view (include .csv at the end):");
      String fileName = input2.nextLine(); //LINE 191

      if (!(fileName.equals("doctorList.csv"))) {
        input2.close();
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
      } else {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        while ((val = br.readLine()) != null) {
          html.append(val);
        }
        br.close();
        input2.close();
        String output = html.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid file input. Terminating program.");
      System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error occured. Terminating program.");
      input2.close();
      System.exit(0);
    }

  }
```

The output/error I get is:

```
Please enter file name you would like to view (include .csv at the end):
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
        at CSV2HTML.secondChance(CSV2HTML.java:191)
        at CSV2HTML.main(CSV2HTML.java:68)
```

Line 68 in the exception is the line where the method is invoked. The code that is in the method for asking user input is identical to the code shown inside the secondChance() method. For reference, here is the code which invokes the secondChance() method:

```java
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid file input. Now initiating second chance.");
      secondChance(); //THIS IS LINE 68
    }
```

**EDIT:** I've added input2 at the top of my code block, to show where/how it is initialized.

Comment: what is line 191? Since that 's where it 's thrown in your code

Comment: What is `input2` and where is is declared and initiated? We can't really tell you what goes wrong when you call `nextLine()` on that Scanner object if you keep it a mystery object by including no details about it.

Comment: In addition to @OH GOD SPIDERS said, what is `file2` and `html`, you don't actually declare them anywhere here.  Also, if `input2` is opened with `new Scanner(System.in)` you should _not_ be calling `.close()` on it.

Comment: @Stultuske line 191 is:  String fileName = input2.nextLine(); (I've added a comment in the code to show where it is, sorry about the confusion)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I've added the code, it's declared within the secondChance() method, right before the try block.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 explanations for `scanner.nextLine()` throwing that exception. From the way you wrote the question, only one of those two is feasible here:

### You have `close()`d System.in!

System.in is your applications standard input. Assuming you just started the app as normal, that'll be 'the keyboard', effectively, which is endless, and therefore that exception cannot *ordinarily* happen. If you start it with `java -jar yourapp.jar <somefile.txt`, you're telling the OS to use `somefile.txt` as 'the keyboard', and that certainly *can* run out of lines, and that's the other unlikely explanation. (If you're actually starting your app that way, then that's your explanation: The scanner's consumed all lines. There's probably a bug in your code which results in reading 'too many' lines, step through with a debugger).

However, you can *close* this resource, which means any further attempts to read from System.in will just fail exactly like you're seeing. The solution is trivial: *Do not ever close `System.in`*.

Scanner is a filter and if you close a scanner, then the scanner closes the underlying resource. Thus, assuming you have a scanner of System.in (`new Scanner(System.in)`), the rule "do no close System.in" expands to: "... *and also never close those scanners either*".

You have either written:

```
scanner.close();
```

or you have written:

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  // stuff with scanner here
}
```

That construct invokes the `close()` method on the thing in the try parentheses when the code 'walks out' of the try block, regardless of how it walks out (control flow, such as a `return` statement, exception thrown, or just run to the end of it).

Some IDEs will notice you're using a class marked as being a resource (or even just anything that can be used in a try-with as above) and will warn you that you should use try-with. **The editor / linting tool is WRONG and you must ignore it**. The concept of 'which things should be closed or not' is vastly more complicated than these simplistic tools act like they are. This is one of those resources that you must in fact *not* close.

Just get rid of it. Delete `scanner.close()` / replace:

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  codeHere();
}
```

with just:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
codeHere();
```